# Export eclipse project to build.sbt

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt

I have a setup with 13 different eclipse projects (mostly scala and java). All projects have dependencies on each other in different ways. Now the project is starting to get big so we want to transition to a build tool and I wanted to try SBT.

First question: Is there any way to export the build files from eclipse? I mean, I have everything working in eclipse so It feels like an "export build.sbt" would be possible.

Second question: I have not found any easy way to add the project dependencies in a sbt file. Some sites say that I should publish all projects to a local maven repo and then using dependencies to be able to build it, but that requirement seems a little extreme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answers by a friendly person on the #sbt irc-channel.

For the first question: No, there seems to be none at the moment.

For the second qestion: I should create a multi-project build and define dependencies between projects that way (following the guide at: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html)

Comment: For the first question, it sounds like something that WOULD be possible, just needs an implementation.

Comment: You are correct in that it would be possible. But as of now there does not seem to exists any implementations on this. I would love a implementation as I often start small in eclipse and then later move it into a build project. :)